# Cumulocity: Two response templates for c8y_Restart, one with and one without <BASE>, why?

Tags: cumulocity

I'm implementing a client to connect to Cloud of Things, which uses Cumulocity. In their example implementation they have a template collection. But the documentation is poor. I found two response templates for c8y_Restart, but don't get the necessity of this.

I already sent Restart-requests from Cumulocity and answered them with my implementation. Status can be set successfully with template 530. 
With template 501 I request all PENDING operations.  But all answers come with response 511 and none on 521.

These are the templates - please ignore the escaped " and new lines - they are from c++ code

```
"10,501,GET,/devicecontrol/operations?deviceId=%%&nocache=true&status=%%,,application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.operationCollection+json,%%,UNSIGNED STRING,\n"
"11,511,$.operations,\"$.c8y_Restart\",\"$.id\",\"$.description\"\n"
"11,521,,\"@.c8y_Restart\",\"@.id\",\"@.description\"\n"
"10,530,PUT,/devicecontrol/operations/%%,application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.operation+json,application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.operation+json,%%,UNSIGNED STRING,\"{\"\"status\"\": \"\"%%\"\"}\"\n"
```

What I get is that `$.operations` is a selector of the list named operations of the parent. Of field `c8y_Restart` `id` and `description` is returned.

The docu of JSONPath says `@` correspond to the current object. When is template 521 useful or used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for SmartREST 1.0 you usually need 2 response templates for operations. The first one (your 511) is for when you query PENDING operations directly. This request always returns an array which is why you need a template with the base of the array ($.operations) in order to loop through it.

The second template is required if you subscribe for real time operations. In this case the operations that you receive are always single objects which is why you mustn't have the $.operations in this template in order to make it work. This is basically your template 521 and this is also why you will not get any response for 521 when querying PENDING operations.

I would recommend to avoid using the @ and always use the $. Using $ you always know what happens but using the @ depends on how Cumulocity manages the JsonPath and it could lead to results you did not intent.

SmartRest 2.0 for MQTT solves the problem of requiring 2 response templates per operation.